# Is static content etag handling broken in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a spring-boot app in which I've tried configuring the content resource strategy for static images.  I've set this config in my application.properties file:

```
spring.resources.chain.cache=true
spring.resources.cache-period=31536000
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/images/**
```

This makes it possible for me to provide urls to image resources that contain the md5hash like this: http://localhost:8080/images/thing-90e8e8d5ff75897cb6068187c460b0b1.png.
When I request this url I get an ETag header like I expect `ETag: "90e8e8d5ff75897cb6068187c460b0b1"`

However, when I make subsequent requests containing the `If-None-Match: "90e8e8d5ff75897cb6068187c460b0b1"` I get a 200 status code and not a 304 as expected.

Debugging into spring classes a bit I've found that the call to `ServletWebRequest.validateIfNoneMatch(String etag)` is always getting a null etag.  It seems like the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(request, response)` does the "not modified" check before it calls setHeaders to decide it's a `VersionedResource` and generate the ETag.

I've managed to reproduce this by cloning and running the example app at https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling.  You can request http://localhost:8080/config-b5c916e3804c81ccd8956ce0bfe79ab0.js, get the `ETag: "b5c916e3804c81ccd8956ce0bfe79ab0"` and request `If-None-Match: "b5c916e3804c81ccd8956ce0bfe79ab0"` and still get a 200 response.

Comment: I can configure the `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` for this path, but it generates it's own MD5 hash for the etag and prefixes it with a 0.  I'd rather not have to generate the MD5 hash twice if it could be avoided. For the time being I've copied `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` and check the request for an existing etag before generating another.  That seems wrong and it feels like this should have worked without this.